# Im trying to type cast a string into an int and it gives me a value error, but only when it's within the loop I define it in

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

The code gives me the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` when I run the following code:

```
message = '071971101726080683243071971136468'
seed = message[-5:]
no_seed_message = message.split(seed)[0]
no_of_chars = int(len(no_seed_message) / 7)

for i in range(no_of_chars + 1):
    encrypted_letter_value = no_seed_message[(i*7)-7:i*7]
    print(int(encrypted_letter_value))
```

but it doesn't give me an error when I run this code:

```
for i in range(no_of_chars + 1):
    encrypted_letter_value = no_seed_message[(i*7)-7:i*7]
print(int(encrypted_letter_value))
```

Why does it only work when I try to type cast outside the loop?

Answer (score 1):

The first iteration of your loop tries to take `no_seed_message[-7:0]` which does not exist. Therefore it tries to convert an empty string `''` to `int`, which gives your error.

It works with the second part because then you only convert *after* the loop, which means only the last value of `encrypted_letter_value` is converted to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to convert `encrypted_letter_value`, for i = 0 `(i*7)-7:i*7` evaluates to `-7:0` and `encrypted_letter_value[0:0]` will retrun `''`, start the loop from `i=1` as `range(1, no_of_chars + 1)`. Use try and except to neglect the empty strings.

```
for i in range(1, no_of_chars + 1):
   try:
      encrypted_letter_value = no_seed_message[(i*7)-7:i*7]
      print(int(encrypted_letter_value))
   except:
      print("Empty String")
```